# Request is null after read in Asp.net core custom Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I found the request in asp.net core custom middleware can be only read once, and after that I have to manually set the request back to the Request.Body. Is this recommended way to read the request?

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    var request = context.Request;
    string xmlstring;
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream m = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        try
        {
            if (request.Body.CanSeek == true) request.Body.Position = 0;
            request.Body.CopyTo(m); 
            xmlstring = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(m.ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    context.Request.Body = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlstring));
    await _next.Invoke(context);
}
```

I tried to "copy" the stream to another one, but doesn't help. I doubt all custom middleware has this step of setting request body back, so here to ask if I do it in proper way.

Answer (score 1):

The correct steps should be:

1. enablerewind
2. read from body
3. do rewind

Please note: without set body back to originalRequestBody, it will only work once, and if you try to call the same web api again, it will fail.

Please see below sample code

```
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {


        var originalRequestBody = context.Request.Body;

        context.Request.EnableRewind();

        try
        {


            using (System.IO.MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
            {
                context.Request.Body.CopyTo(m);

                var s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(m.ToArray());
            }

            //this line will rewind the request body, so it could be read again
            context.Request.Body.Position = 0;

            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            //important, otherwise, even current request will succeed, following request will fail
            context.Request.Body = originalRequestBody;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I would recommend to test this solution in a dummy project, rather than copy/paste to your existing projects. Prove the theory first and then identify why it is not working in real projec